# python3: numpy works, but numpy.integrate doesn't

Tags: python, numpy, python-import

I'm using `numpy` for mathematical projects in `python3`. Today, I wanted to use [`numpy.integrate.quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html), but you can see the errors and further attemps below. `import numpy` always works. So what's the matter?

```
$ python
Python 3.6.1 (default, Mar 27 2017, 00:27:06) 
[GCC 6.3.1 20170306] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import numpy.integrate as integrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.integrate'
>>> import scipy.integrate as integrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
>>> from numpy import integrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'integrate'
>>> from scipy import integrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
>>> from numpy.integrate import quad
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.integrate'
>>> from numpy import integrate.quad
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from numpy import integrate.quad
```

Numpy seems to be installed correctly, but I still can't use numpy.integrate. Am I messing with the imports?

Comment: There is no `numpy.integrate.quad`. Take another look at the name listed in that documentation you linked.

Comment: I do know that it's listed as `scipy.integrate.quad` there. But as you can see, using `scipy` instead of `numpy` doesn't work either. Your comment is not constructive to me, could you please specify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Install scipy, dude.

Comment: You're right, didn't know that scipy and numpy are different modules. Thought that numpy contained them all. Thanks, that solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
```

numpy doesn't have an `integrate` *package*; those are in the `scipy` part of the delivery.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but I didn't knew that I had to install `scipy` as a seperate package :) Thought `numpy` contained everything.

Comment: It's a large learning process.  Check the NumPy / SciPy documentation carefully, now that you know the problem's root.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that :)